# How to prevent duplicates for ItemCount?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a list of matches that are associated to a nation. Now in the iteration I assign this nation for each match, so for example:

```
Team A = Italy
Team B = Italy
```

I bind this matches in a GridView like this:

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#4F4F4F">
  <Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Orange" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      <TextBlock Text=" match" FontSize="22" Foreground="White" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Expander.Header>
  <ItemsPresenter />
</Expander>
```

Where name is the nation name, anyway, the problem is that ItemCount grab Italy for two times. I need to prevent this situation in xaml and not display the duplicated items, is this possible?

Comment: You have not provided enough details. I would need to be Nostradamus to be able to answer

Comment: Can you post the code where you set `ItemCount`?

Comment: The XAML looks largely irrelevant here... It only shows what you have already computed. How about the C# code that fills the list?

Comment: I've published a new question about this situation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549818/cannot-bind-list-of-items-in-gridview-column @Liero

Comment: Don't repost questions like that. You have an _edit_ button here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and assume you have a generic `List` of some type labeled as `Team`.

Try this:

```
List<Team> teams = new List<Team>
{
    new Team {Name = "Italy"},
    new Team {Name = "France"},
    new Team {Name = "Italy"}
};

var distinctList = teams.Select(team => team.Name)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Select(team => new Team {Name = team})
                        .OrderBy(team => team.Name)
                        .ToList();
```

Be very careful as this is not optimized for performance, this will simply just give you the results you desire. Do not use this if your dataset is extremely large, otherwise you will need to compensate for the loading time potentially. Also you may want to include some class type with `IEqualityComparer` to accommodate for `StringComparison`. The comparer will then be passed as an argument to `Distinct()`.

As for ItemCount just simply set that variable in your ViewModel once you have obtained the `distinctList`.

```
this.ItemCount = distinctList.Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is ambiguous but I guess that you didn't group by your results based on the your city name.