# How to bind a list of item in CollectionViewSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm stuck in this problem for days. Never found a solution. So I've a list of items called `Country`, in this list I've also another list of items called `League`. I've create a CollectionViewSource for organize all of this in nation name and league name but I can't bind all the leagues name:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Country}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name" />
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="League.Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I should write: `<PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="League[0].Name" />`

but this only will bind the first item of the league list. Any solution?

**PRACTICE EXAMPLE**

suppose that there are two countries (Italy, England), Italy country have two leagues (Serie A and Serie B) and England have (Premiere League) only.
Serie A and Serie B contains in total 3 matches, 2 in Serie A and 1 in Serie B. In premiere League there are 4 matches.
In the ListView organization as my other topic that [you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549818/cannot-bind-list-of-items-in-gridview-column), in the UI should be displayed this structure:

```
ITALY
    SERIE A
          INTER
          MILAN
    SERIE B
          JUVENTUS
ENGLAND
    PREMIERE LEAGUE
          LEICESTER
          MANCHESTER UNITED
          MANCHESTER CITY
          LIVERPOOL
```

Now Italy and england are disposed into groupstyle as serie a, serie b and premiere league, with an expander (as you can see in my other question) there is the matches for each leagues.
The problem's that in the CollectionViewSource I cannot display the name of the league 'cause the leagues are inside a list, the same problem is for the matches, that is a list available in league, data structure:

```
Nations->Leagues->Matches
```

Comment: Post more cs code, please to get what you want exactly.

Comment: @EliArbel I posted a more complete scenario here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549818/cannot-bind-list-of-items-in-gridview-column unfortunately no one has answered

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I need to organize the groupdescription by nation name and leagues name

Comment: So you mean grouping the nation names and in each group you want grouping the leagues??

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer exactly

Comment: Doing this based on your UI how you show these information, because it is seems like a master detail data presentation.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I do not clearly understand your affirmation. You could rephrase?

Comment: show me how you want to show these groups; (TreeView, ListView, Datagrid, ... )?, base on your answer i can determine the way to show the groups.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer check my update please

Comment: Please show some image what you want to display. Or show some text based sketch.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan you can find an example rapresentation here: http://www.soccerway.com/ "now playing" section. The site only missing nation group. I've [NATION] that contains [LEAGUES] each league contains [MATCHES].

Comment: @Heisenberg Groupby is not needed here.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I've only two groupstyle, in the first I need to put all nation and in the second the leagues...

Comment: @Heisenberg and what you are using for display ? DataGrid/ItemsControl ?

Comment: I'm using listview with groupstyle, please check the xaml here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549818/cannot-bind-list-of-items-in-gridview-column @AnjumSKhan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent GroupDescriptions duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295206/prevent-groupdescriptions-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went by the output you want. Please check and tell if this is what you want.

```
public partial class WinExpander : Window
{
    public WinExpander()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
} 

public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Countries = new List<Country>();
        }
    }

public class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<League> Leagues { get; set; }

        public Country()
        {
            Leagues = new List<League>();
        }
    }

    public class League
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Match> Matches { get; set; }

        public League()
        {
            Matches = new List<Match>();
        }
    }

    public class Match
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedItems" Source="{Binding Countries}"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}" Margin="25 0 0 0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Matches}" Margin="25 0 0 0">
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </Expander>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>         
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
```

You can replace any of the `ItemsControl` with `ListBox` too.

**Another solution using `GroupStyle` and `ListView` according to user requirements.**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedItems" Source="{Binding Countries}">
     <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
         <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" Name="Playing">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Leagues">                        
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}" Margin="25 0 0 0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFBCDAEC">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Very good answer, I'm testing your code and trying to convert to GroupStyle, is that possible? check my group style structure here for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549818/cannot-bind-list-of-items-in-gridview-column

Comment: @Heisenberg i cannot understand why you want to use grouping here. Grouping is something else. Still I will try to convert to GroupStyle.

Comment: The groupstyle show a better structure for me, I'll try to convert your code into groupstyle. I hope for your help, thanks :)

Comment: do you have any news?

Comment: @Heisenberg Was out to purchase vegetables, fruits etc in our weekly market in India. Now online.

Comment: @Heisenberg Please see added answer and output screenshot too.

Comment: Nice updating thanks :) Just a little thing: is possible make league name, in you example (Serie 1, Serie 2, Premiere League) as groupstyle too? PS: I'm on chat as Harold

Comment: @Heisenberg Hi, I have done your work applying grouping for league names too. Come on chat !

Comment: thanks, I'm on work now, please contact me here: amministrazione@exarco.it