# Show collection of groupdescription from a list as source

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for the misleading title. Anyway I'll try to explain better. I want to show collection within collections in a ListView. But the display should use Expanders to show inner collection items. All the items should appear in their appropriate columns. Actually what I did is this:

**XAML**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedItems" Source="{Binding Countries}">
 <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
     <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
 </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" Name="Playing">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Leagues">                        
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}" Margin="25 0 0 0">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFBCDAEC">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

The code above show in the expander the name of the country but unfortunately I can't manage to show as list of expander the countries name that are inside of a list.

I want to show expander for leagues too and corresponding matches should appear in the appropriate column. In my ViewModel, I have a collection of Country, and each `Country>Leagues collection >Matches` collection.

See the classes below :

```
public partial class WinExpander : Window
{
    public WinExpander()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
} 

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Countries = new List<Country>();
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<League> Leagues { get; set; }

    public Country()
    {
        Leagues = new List<League>();
    }
}

public class League
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Match> Matches { get; set; }

    public League()
    {
        Matches = new List<Match>();
    }
}

public class Match
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

1. Use `Expander` for `Matches`. To show `Matches` in sync with `Leagues`, sync both `Leagues` Expander and `Matches` Expander. When we expand a `League`, corresponding `Matches` expander will expand too.
2. For proper look and feel, we have to remove the `Expander Icon` from `Match` column.
3. To sync `League` and `Match` `Expanders`, introduce a property called 'IsExpanded' in `League`. Now `League` class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` .

   ```
   bool _isExpanded=true;
   public bool IsExpanded
   {
       get { return _isExpanded; }
       set { _isExpanded = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded"); }
   }
   ```

ListView markup :

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" Name="Playing">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Country" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Leagues">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl Margin="25 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" >
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Matches}">
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Match">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl Margin="25 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Leagues}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Expander Style="{StaticResource MatchExpanderStyle}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5">                                                
                                                <Expander.Header>
                                                    <TextBlock Visibility="Hidden" FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </Expander.Header>
                                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Matches}">
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        ...
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Put this entire thing under `Window.Resources` or, `Application.Resources`. I have changed the `Visibility` to Hidden in `ToggleButton` with name `HeaderSite`. Everything is generated automatically by VS.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#222"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke" Color="#FF526C7B"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#FF003366"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke" Color="DarkGray"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#666"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Fill" Color="Transparent"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke" Color="DarkGray"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke" Color="#666"/>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderRightHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderUpHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="19"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                                    <TransformCollection>
                                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                                    </TransformCollection>
                                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
                                        <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="1" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual">
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border>
                                <Rectangle Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                            <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="19"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" Fill="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Fill}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Circle.Stroke}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M 1,1.5 L 4.5,5 L 8,1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="false" Stroke="{StaticResource Expander.Static.Arrow.Stroke}" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4.5  L 4.5,1  L 8,4.5"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.MouseOver.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Pressed.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Stroke}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="circle" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Circle.Fill}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource Expander.Disabled.Arrow.Stroke}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="MatchExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" Visibility="Hidden" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderFocusVisual}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Right">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Right"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderRightHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Left">
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Left"/>
                                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Right"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderLeftHeaderStyle}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Everything else remains same as in older answer here : [How to bind a list of item in CollectionViewSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551511/how-to-bind-a-list-of-item-in-collectionviewsource/38553062#38553062)

Comment: Thanks for this, actually I can't test your code, I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks again :)

Comment: @lokusking see the answer plz